# C++ stream to memory

Tags: c++, stream

how can I create `std::ostream` and `std::istream` objects to point to a piece of memory I allocated and manage (I don't want the stream to free my memory).

I was looking at using `rdbuf()->pubsetbuf()` to modify one of the other streams - say `sstringstream`.  However I think streambuf used by `stringstream` will free the buffer afterwards?

Basically I'm trying to serialize some things to shared memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [bufferstream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html#interprocess.streams.bufferstream) class in the [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) library:

> The bufferstream classes offer
>   iostream interface with direct
>   formatting in a fixed size memory
>   buffer with protection against buffer
>   overflows.

Comment: I'm curious about the down vote. Did someone have a problem with this solution?

Comment: don't suggest Boost. Many companies can't put Boost into their code. My own (Microsoft), included.

Comment: @ericfrazer boost is fine for many. No downvote needed because of it.

Comment: it's not an answer. it's a library many don't want to include.

Comment: it's like being asked how to tune and engine and being told "buy a new car"

Comment: @ericfrazer this is the most upvoted answer, because it IS, an answer. It's not buy a new car, but buy an aftermarket part.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>

//...
size_t length = 100;
auto pBuf = new char[length]; // allocate memory

struct membuf: std::streambuf // derive because std::streambuf constructor is protected
{
   membuf(char* p, size_t size) 
   {
       setp( p, p + size); // set start end end pointers
   }
   size_t written() {return pptr()-pbase();} // how many bytes were really written?
};

membuf sbuf( pBuf, length ); // our buffer object
std::ostream out( &sbuf );   // stream using our buffer

out << 12345.654e10 << std::endl;
out.flush();

std::cout << "Nr of written bytes: " << sbuf.written() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Content: " << (char*)pBuf << std::endl;

//...
delete [] pBuf; // free memory
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703823/a-custom-ostream

Answer (score 1):

A minimal memory buffer has to implement only the [`overflow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) function of [`std::streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) and keep track of the [pointers of the streambuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pptr). This is done via [`setp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/setp) and [`pbump`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pbump).

You will also need to add an underlying memory buffer, but this can be done rather easy. cppreference.com has a good example of an implementation based on an `std::array` in the already mentioned page for the [`overflow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) function. While this is a good start to learn, you might want to have a memory buffer that can resize. You can try to implement it based on an `std::vector` (like I did [here](https://gist.github.com/stephanlachnit/4a06f8475afd144e73235e2a2584b000)).

I ended up writing a memory buffer based on `std::realloc` to get the most performance while also giving me the possibility to hand the raw pointer over to C libaries. You can find my implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/stephanlachnit/272e5eb82c0e2a1cccd55af5d6b73e2b).

Comment: Hey Stephan, apart from fixing a small typo, I removed that "get" from "get pointers" in my edit, but that may have been a mistake from me. (I was focusing on "output" etc., and got confused by that "get", or at least by "why only get"... I'm still kinda confused, honestly; I'm no iostream expert...) Would you prefer a rollback?