# How to your own C++ cout << like object

Tags: c++

I was just asking if you can create your own cout<< like object in C++. most people confuse my question with operator overloading <<. But no, i dont want to implement my own << operator so that when users print my object i can control what they get. But basically i want to implement like this:

```
something << some_given << some_end;
```

Not sure if that is possible , but the iostream standard library created the cout , so my mind says "Why not?". So i asked stackoverflow. Help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: What is `something` in this case?

Comment: I think op wants to make a `cout` object, but not `cout`. I think op understands about how to use `operator<<` on different objects (e.g. output to file etc), but wants to make a `cout` that isn't `cout`.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement your own  stream handler?

Comment: yes @kfsone thanks! I was looking for that

Comment: @Tas yes thats what i wanted

Comment: @Dsafds see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703823/a-custom-ostream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I interpretted your question correctly but I think you want a class with an overloaded operator<< so that's what i have here

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() = default;
    MyClass& operator<<(int input) {
      //do something with input
      return *this;
    }
}
```

You would use it like this;

```
MyClass myObject;
myObject << 42;
//the function would have been called
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i wanted!

Comment: best way is to make `operator <<` return reference, like this: `MyClass &operator << (...);` so you would be able to write several << in one line: `myObject << 42 << 37 << 14;`.