# "Overriding" non-virtual operator << (...) in user stream

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, ostream

I made my own stream class inherited from `std::ostream` with a template insertion operator:

```cpp
class MyOstream : public std::ostream 
{
   ...
   template <typename T>
   std::ostream & operator << (T value)
   {
      ...
      return std::ostream::operator<<(value);
   }
}
```

Also, I have a function that gets a reference to a `std::ostream` as an argument:

```cpp
void some_func(std::ostream & stream) 
{
   stream << "Hello World!";
}
```

I want to somehow call `MyOstream::operator<<()` in `some_func()`, but the problem is that `std::ostream::operator<<()` is not virtual (actually, there are multiple overloaded operators + several friend operators) and I can't override it as usual.

Is there any way to do this without changing the interface of `some_func()`?

**Addition**

Function `some_func(...)` gets an object of `MyOstream` class as a parameter.

**Addition #2**

Actually I have my own `MyStreambuf` inherited from `std::streambuf`, which provides all the logic, MyOstream class is just needed to access to binary data. `MyStreambuf` class is used to restrict size of data, that user can write (let it be 500B). So, if object of `MyStreambuf` currently contains 450B of data and user will try to write 100B it'll cause setting of std::ios_base::badbit and refusing data. If user then try to write 10B, which is absolutely valid, it fails, cause of badbit set. That is the real problem.

So, the real problem I'm trying to overcome is calling `clear()` before each attempt to write.

Comment: afaik `std::ostream` is not meant to be used as base class, but [`std::basic_ios`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) is.

Comment: there are only very few classes in the standard library that are meant to be inherited from. Don't use inheritance as the default goto solution

Comment: in different words: Why do you inherit from `std::ostream` ? The aim is to use `some_func` without modifying it, right? What is the actual stream you want to write to?

Comment: The usual way to handle this is to derive from `std::streambuf` instead, and then pass an instance of it to the constructor of a standard `std::ostream`. You can't override non-virtual `operator<<`, but you can still implement what actions are performed when the stream is written to. See [A custom ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703823/)

Comment: Do you have a reason to specialize `std::ostream` instead of `std::streambuf`?

Comment: First question to ask yourself is why you want your own stream class? And then ensure that it is in fact the proper solution for the problem you have.