# C++ Interface for logger

Tags: c++, logging

I am working a big legacy project and need to redo the common logger.
I tried to make same logger interface with before to avoiding changing ton of loggers.
The reason I need to redo the logger is the old one is syslog UDP which was using built-in library functions, while the new one I'm using GELF UDP.

Suppose I have a log with two parts of message, severity is info. The old interface is like below:

```
Log_INFO<< "First part message" <<"Second part message"<< endl;
```

Log_INFO is like 'std::cout', but it has two functionality:

1. Print out message in the command line.
2. Collect it in Graylog.

My new function is like below:

```
//Severity = {debug,info,warning, error, critical}
Log(Severity, whole_message)
```

For the same example,

```
Log("info",first_part_message+ second_part_message)
```

My question is how can I make my function is able to read log like the old one.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to know

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what your question is?

Comment: What's wrong with the old interface? Especially considering that `first_part_message+ second_part_message` will likely not work very well for all but a few cases.

Comment: The question is missing...

Comment: Did you ask the question previously, something about turning the `log` function into a macro, or I am just having deja vu? I very particularly remember responding to a question also with the variable name `Log_INFO`...

Comment: I just added more explanation for this question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

One common way of doing this is creating a custom `streambuf`-derived class, say `LogStreambuf`, and an `ostream`-derived class, say `LogStream`, that uses `LogStreambuf` (but is otherwise a plain jane `ostream`).

Then your log objects would be

```
LogStream Log_INFO("info");
LogStream Log_WARN("warn");
```

etc.

Your custom streambuf probably should call your `Log` function from its `sync` method.

See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703823/a-custom-ostream) for an example, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524641/how-do-i-create-my-own-ostream-streambuf) for further guidance.